# coalesce on sample database not work

Tags: sql, db2, ibm-data-studio

Here I'm using the SAMPLE Database of DB2.

I'm trying to use coalesce to change the null values in MIDINIT column of EMPLOYEE table but I still get the null values result after I run the code.

```
SELECT COALESCE (MIDINIT, 'XX') AS MIDINIT
FROM EMPLOYEE;
```

[run result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Ik2R.png)

Comment: which DBMS are you using..?

Comment: IBM Data Studio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what is your error?

if MIDINIT is not a char or a varchar (example is integer), your coalesce replace a integer value by char value and system SQL cant choice the type

if MIDINIT is not a char or a varchar you should be

```
SELECT COALESCE (cast(MIDINIT as varchar(200)), 'XX') AS MIDINIT
FROM EMPLOYEE;
```

or if MIDINIT  is numeric

```
SELECT COALESCE (MIDINIT, 0) AS MIDINIT
FROM EMPLOYEE;
```

you can use ifnull function to replace coalesce if you want ( if MIDINIT is char or varchar):

```
SELECT ifnull(MIDINIT, 'XX') AS MIDINIT
FROM EMPLOYEE;
```

Comment: actually no error, but the null values still present and not changed to 'XX'

Comment: are you sur its null value? Its not blank value? try:    select nullif(cast(yourcolumn as varchar(200)), '') from your table

Comment: try select '#' ||trim(yourcolumn) || '#' from yourtable if result is ## then your column is not null

Comment: I don't know if it's null or not, because if it's null value coalesce or that code will solve it.

Comment: I got ## result, so I think It's not null.

Comment: try this SELECT COALESCE(nullif(trim(cast(MIDINIT as varchar(200))), ''), 'XX') AS MIDINIT FROM EMPLOYEE;  or use a case